# How to set a timeout to a MFC Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

I need to create a thread that tries to execute a function in a specific amount of time. If the thread did not get success, I need to finish him with a number that indicates an error.

I am trying to do this because of a external library of my program that I have to execute, but sometimes enter in an infinity loop in a search of a resource that is not ready yet and the program break waiting for that function.

Comment: did you start the development process? please, share your code

Comment: Remember that if you terminate a thread any locks and external resources it holds will NOT be released.

Comment: And, while correct, @RichardCritten's comment doesn't sound even half as dangerous as it should. A common scenario where locks play a central role is in serializing heap access. If you [TerminateThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717.aspx) a thread, while it is in the middle of allocating memory, any subsequent attempt to allocate memory from the same heap will wait on a lock, that never gets released. So you exchanged and infinite loop with a deadlock. That's a step in some direction, just not forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot solve this by offloading the faulting implementation onto another thread in the same process, because there is no way to safely shut down that thread, in case it runs afoul. Calling [TerminateThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717.aspx) is the only way to take down a thread from the outside. Due to the consequences, it cannot be used when a process must continue to run reliably.

> For example, **TerminateThread** can result in the following problems:
>
> - If the target thread owns a critical section, the critical section will not be released.
> - If the target thread is allocating memory from the heap, the heap lock will not be released.
> - If the target thread is executing certain kernel32 calls when it is terminated, the kernel32 state for the thread's process could be inconsistent.
> - If the target thread is manipulating the global state of a shared DLL, the state of the DLL could be destroyed, affecting other users of the DLL.

Your only options are:

1. Request a bugfix from the vendor of the 3rd party library.
2. Offload the 3rd party library into its own process. In this surrogate process you can run the 3rd party library on its own thread, and if it doesn't return in time (use [WaitForSingleObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032.aspx) with a timeout value to determine that condition), call [ExitProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682658.aspx) to end the misery. You will have to implement [interprocess communications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574.aspx) between your processes for this to work.